# Issue with work profile deletion. Remove profile left work profile half deleted

Tags: work-profiles

Having an issue with work profile, created through Mobile Iron Go.
After de-registering the device, tried removing work profile. On selecting "Delete" on prompt, the profile got deleted from Accounts. But re-installing Mobile Iron Go is not allowing re-configuration:

The message I am seeing is:

> You have set up a work profile. To continue using MobileIron Go, please use the badged version of the application

Is there any way to remove work profile left-overs without resetting mobile or removing cache from recovery console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to delete the work profile.

Reference: [OnePlus Forum discussion thread](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/how-to-disable-work-profile.623181/#post-17832910)

Root cause: Oreo allows to have more than one work profile and OnePlus was adding a work profile by default (not sure).

We have to use adb to remove it.

These are the commands:

```
adb shell pm list users
```

Now you will get this list of users (or profiles) running in your device:

```
Users:
UserInfo{0:Your Name:13} running
UserInfo{999:Multi-App:4000030} running
```

In this case, the default profile ("Your Name") has the USER_ID 0, and the work profile has the user USER_ID 999.
The second one is the one created by OnePlus to get parallel apps, so you have to launch a command to remove it:

```
adb shell pm remove-user 999
```

And there you go. Work profile deleted successfully.